# stopping ghci from displaying modules in the prompt

Tags: haskell, prompt, read-eval-print-loop, ghci

When I start a session in ghci, I use:

```
:set prompt >>
```

However, some function calls still display module names at the prompt when evaluated. I never want anything other than my custom prompt, I think.

1. How do I suppress this display?
2. What exactly is the prompt trying to show me? Why does it only do this for some function calls and not all of them? I don't understand the logic of what is happening.

Actual ghci output:

```
>>m00 <- iOIandRTfromPhrase 0.25 2 2 4 [2] 2 [2] 4.0 3                                                                                                       
>>rs <- newMMap [("100",m00)]                                                                                                                                
>>:{                                                                                                                                                         
*ExperimentalConductive ExperimentalConductive Music.Theory.Bjorklund SuperDirtAction NonlinearEnsemble EnsembleNew Control.Concurrent Data.List| let lsysTest rules axiom gen phraseLength = do                                                                                                                           
*ExperimentalConductive ExperimentalConductive Music.Theory.Bjorklund SuperDirtAction NonlinearEnsemble EnsembleNew Control.Concurrent Data.List|     f <- flatRandomPattern gen rules axiom [0.25,0.5..1.5] phraseLength                                                                                                  
*ExperimentalConductive ExperimentalConductive Music.Theory.Bjorklund SuperDirtAction NonlinearEnsemble EnsembleNew Control.Concurrent Data.List|     return f                                                                                                                                                             
*ExperimentalConductive ExperimentalConductive Music.Theory.Bjorklund SuperDirtAction NonlinearEnsemble EnsembleNew Control.Concurrent Data.List| :}         
>>:{                                                                                                                                                         
*ExperimentalConductive ExperimentalConductive Music.Theory.Bjorklund SuperDirtAction NonlinearEnsemble EnsembleNew Control.Concurrent Data.List| let lsysTestB rules axiom gen iois phraseLength = do 
*ExperimentalConductive ExperimentalConductive Music.Theory.Bjorklund SuperDirtAction NonlinearEnsemble EnsembleNew Control.Concurrent Data.List|     f <- flatRandomPattern gen rules axiom iois phraseLength
*ExperimentalConductive ExperimentalConductive Music.Theory.Bjorklund SuperDirtAction NonlinearEnsemble EnsembleNew Control.Concurrent Data.List|     return f                                                                                                                                                             
*ExperimentalConductive ExperimentalConductive Music.Theory.Bjorklund SuperDirtAction NonlinearEnsemble EnsembleNew Control.Concurrent Data.List| :}         
>>
```

Setting prompt-cont doesn't change the output, it seems.

> > :set prompt-cont |
> >     Some flags have not been recognized: prompt-cont, |
> >     :{
> >     *ExperimentalConductive ExperimentalConductive Music.Theory.Bjorklund SuperDirtAction NonlinearEnsemble EnsembleNew Control.Concurrent Data.List| let lsys rules axiom gen phraseLength iOIs = do

Answer, from leftaroundabout below: older ghci needs set prompt2. Newer versions might require different commands, as described in comments below.

Comment: daniel is experiencing this problem, as shown in this screen shot: https://twitter.com/danielmkarlsson/status/1022258418252435456

Comment: The reason I want to do this is to make it easier to read what I've posted to ghci. Sometimes the prompt even takes up multiple lines, which isn't helpful, particularly when I've evaluated a block of code.

Comment: post edited to include ghci output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, that is indeed a prompt problem, but not a `prompt` problem. `:{ :}` Continuations in GHCi use a different prompt, namely `prompt-cont`.

```
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set prompt >>
>>:set prompt-cont | 
>>:{
|let foo :: [Int]
|    foo = [37, 9, 18]
|:}
>>foo
[37,9,18]
```

In older GHCi versions, `prompt-cont` was called `prompt2`:

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set prompt >>
>>:set prompt2 |
>>:{
|let foo :: [Int]
|    foo = [37, 9, 18]
|:}
>>foo
[37,9,18]
```

I recommend you also check out [`IHaskell`](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell) if you like a REPL with proper capability of defining functions in local code blocks. GHCi's support for this was always a bit fiddly.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but the output doesn't change. I've updated the original post above to show output after set prompt-cont.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these (prompt-cont, prompt-function, prompt-cont-function) changes the output.

Comment: Ah, you're probably using an old GHC version. These flags were renamed recently.

Comment: OK. You found it. The one I need is set prompt2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly the verbose version is telling me?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Before setting prompt2, the prompt was verbose. What is the purpose of listing those modules, and which modules exactly is it listing?

Comment: I don't think there's any good purpose of this. Most people just don't use continuations in GHCi at all, and those who do probably have the prompt shortened in their `.ghci` file.

Comment: @renick promp-cont by default shows you the currently loaded modules.